# How can i get the current location in iphone application?

Tags: xcode, cllocationmanager, mkreversegeocoder

I got the longitude and latitude values and i saved it in a label and it was easily displayed in my application but i want the current location details, mainly the name of the place.
I used MKReverseGeocoder. i did this code

```
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
    coord.longitude=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"LATITUDE: %f", location.coordinate.latitude];

    MKReverseGeocoder *geocoder=[[MKReverseGeocoder alloc]initWithCoordinate:coord];
    [geocoder setDelegate:self];
    [geocoder  start];



    latlbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LATITUDE: %f", location.coordinate.latitude];
    lonlbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LONGITUDE: %f", location.coordinate.longitude];
    //txtlocate.text = [location description];

}
![-(void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{
NSLog(@"%@",\[placemark addressDictionary\]
     }
```

[image]
this is the error what i'm getting...
thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clear:

> Assigning to 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' (aka 'double') from incompatible type 'id'

`coord` is `CLLocationCoordinate2D` type:

```
typedef struct {
    CLLocationDegrees latitude;
    CLLocationDegrees longitude;
} CLLocationCoordinate2D;
```

And `latitude`, `longitude` are CLLocationDegrees:

```
typedef double CLLocationDegrees;
```

So you cannot assign NSString (it's an `id` type either) object to `coord.longitude` nor `coord.latitude`.

---

EDIT:

You should do it like:

```
coord.longitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
```

Comment: how can i change that two coordinates as double?

Comment: @goku both of them are double type which is just type defined as CLLocationDegrees. See the new version of the answer. :)